# How random cut forest deals with periodicity / seasonality?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, anomaly-detection, opensearch, rcf

I'm using Anomaly Detection in Kibana (opendistro/opensearch) and I'm trying to understand how AWS SageMaker Random Cut Forest deals with periodicities and does the "detector interval" affect on it ?

For example I tried with simple datas which contains only "0" and "1" values : there is "1" all the time, and only one hour per day (at the same time every day) there are "0". So in my datas there is seasonality not anomaly but...
The algorithm detects anomalies every day if I set up the detector interval to 10min or 1min but if I put it at 60min, it doesn't detect anymore. I really don't understand how it works...

[image]

On this screenshot, we clearly can see that it detects anomalies that should be actually a seasonality.
To understand it, I need to understand how random cut forest deals with seasonalities. Does it only cut datas in the trees or does it create new features based on date like "NumberoOfTheDay", "Month", "Year" to treat well seasonalities?